# Is there a way to automatically update a certain field after certain time?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, auto-update, vs-web-site-project

I am creating an website using node.js, express.js, and mongoose and I have one field that needs to be updated after a certain time so my question is there a way to do that ? Or I have to use cron? Thank you for your answer.

Comment: You need to use Cron

Comment: What does "update one field" mean?  Is this something in your database?  Something displayed in a web page?

Comment: @jfriend00 I want to ban a user for 30 mins after 3 tries so that's why I wan to update the attempts field automatically after 30 mins

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily need to use cron.

For example, you could use `setTimeout()` or `setInterval()` (https://nodejs.org/uk/docs/guides/timers-in-node/) to achieve this functionality inside your application with the simplest means possible.

Also, there are libraries like `cron` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron) which handle these timeouts/intervals for you and are nice if you prefer cron-style syntax without having to deal with os-side infrastructure or don't have any access to it.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to update a field when the ban expires.  Instead, put a future time in the field for when that ban expires.  Then whenever they attempt to connect or login, you just check if the time in the field has passed.  If not, they aren't allowed in.  If so, then they are allowed in.  This is much more efficient than trying to clear a field in 30 minutes.  Just put a time for 30 minutes from now in the field and check that time anytime they connect.

Comment: I did that but I have to click an extra submit button after the time expires even though the password is right and then after that click it will reset the attempts back to 0 and so it will work again

Comment: @Gagan - Well, that's a side effect of your implementation, not an architecture problem.  I'm sure you could fix that if you wanted to.